# ASP.NET Regular Expression Validator

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need a Regular Expression that can validate an exact 3 character(alpha only) code but also a blank field to set as the validation expression of a ASP.NET RegEx validator control.
I am currently using `^[a-zA-Z]{3}$`
and this works out well to match the code but of course doesn't match a blank.
I have been looking at using something like this:
`^(?:|)[a-zA-Z]{3}$`

Comment: Where a blank field means any amount of white space, or nothing entered at all?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it should allow blank with no white space, which according to @Ahmad Mageed I do not need to change the initial RegEx since it won't check the blank field

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your intention is to allow blank fields, then use the original pattern of `^[a-zA-Z]{3}$` since the `RegularExpressionValidator` doesn't validate blank fields. It will allow them.

However, if you want to prevent blank entries then you'll need to add a [`RequiredFieldValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) to validate the same control, in addition to the `RegularExpressionValidator`.

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants it to NOT be required.  Do you think he would be ok with just the expression he has (`^[A-Za-Z]{3}$`)?  +1

Comment: From what I understand OP wanted to allow empty field. RequiredFieldValidator won't allow empty field.

Comment: @agent-j if the field is optional and can be blank, then the `RegularExpressionValidator` alone is sufficient since it will let blank entries through. To prevent blank entries the OP will need to use the `RequiredFieldValidator` in conjunction with the other validator.

Comment: @agent-j, @Peri: updated to clarify. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Thank you, I want to allow a blank field so I will leave the initial regex and put the RequiredFieldValidator on the required fields in the form and leave it off the one that allows blanks, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using (^$)|(^[a-zA-Z]{3}$)?